Galois Cohomology mod 2 of iterated Laurent series
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic different from two.
For $n\geq 1$, set $F_n=k((X_1))\cdots ((X_n))$, and let  $F=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\geq 1}F_n$.
If $I=\{i_1,\ldots,i_m\}$ is a non empty subset of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, set $(X_I)=(X_{i_1})\cup \cdots \cup (X_{i_m})\in H^m(F,\mu_2)$.
I think I convinced myself that for all $1\leq j\leq n$, the elements $(X_I), I\subset \{1,\ldots,n\}, \vert I \vert =j$, form an $\mathbb{F}_2$-basis of the vector space $H^j(F_n,\mu_2)$.
Question 1. Is is correct ?
Question 2. Does a similar result holds true for the vector spaces $H^j(F,\mu_2)$? More precisely, is the following true:
For every non empty subset of $\mathbb{N}^*$, and for all $j\geq 1$, is true that the elements $(X_I), I\subset \mathbb{N}^*, \vert I \vert =j$, form an $\mathbb{F}_2$-basis of the vector space $H^j(F,\mu_2)$ ?
I think that the answer to question 2 should be proved to be YES if one can justify that for all $j,n\geq 1$, the maps $H^j(F_n,\mu_2)\to H^j(F,\mu_2)$ are injective.
Is it simply because the absolute Galois group of $F$ is (but is it ,really ?) the inverse limit of  the absolute Galois groups of the various $F_n$'s ?
Apologies if all of this is trivial.
